# Retrieving a JSON from an API on Node and sending to HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use a Javascript API called 'cryptocompare' to use its functions to call for particular data to print to an index.html.

**Snippet of server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
const cc = require('cryptocompare');

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on 3000');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  // cc
  //   .coinList()
  //   .then(coinList => {
  //     console.log(coinList[0]);
  //   })
  //   .catch(console.error);

  cc.price('BTC', ['USD']).then(prices => {
    //console.log(prices);
    // -> { USD: 1100.24, EUR: 1039.63 }
    var BTCprice = prices;
    console.log(BTCprice.USD);
  });


});
```

So far I've managed to get the function to retrieve JSON data of `BTCprice.USD`

I'm just trying to find the next way of sending this data, that I can console.log on my bash terminal, to an element on an index.html file.

Any help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a templating engine for this. For an example, you can install pug.

```
npm install pug --save
```

Then ask express js to use pug for rendering.

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
```

Create a Pug template file named index.pug in the views directory, with the following content:

```
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1= message
```

And change your code to something like the following

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

cc.price('BTC', ['USD']).then(prices => {
    //console.log(prices);
    // -> { USD: 1100.24, EUR: 1039.63 }
    var BTCprice = prices;
    res.render('index', { title: 'USD', message: 'Price is '+BTCprice.USD });

  });
});
```

All this information is from http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried this however the index.pug file isn't rendering any of the information I input in `res. render`?